# How to quick search transaction histories in Ethereum without WebAPI?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, parity, geth

I want to quick search the transaction histories in Ethereum, without WebAPI like Etherscan.io.
But I can not.

Please tell me, how to quick search like etherscan.io, etherchain.org and gastracker.io.

### Needed function

1. Search

   - For search 100 result need 5 sec below.
2. Below 5 clients use at the same time for search.

   - `Etherscan.io` have limit on WebAPI.
3. Quick sync

   - Less delay between Ethereum network like Etherscan.io.
4. Without etherscan.io, etherchain.org and gastracker.io, other same service.

### Tried tasks

#### Use Geth + Web3.js + Node.js + MySQL

This is no good. Because, A SELECT SQL has many time for run.
I tried make a system, myself.
My transaction histories search function has 10 sec, search from 5,902,085 block to 4,900,637.(limit 100 result.)
And need many sync time, because should copy transaction history to MySQL from Geth(via web3.js).
Therefore, this is no good.

#### Use Parity.js only

Parity has `transaction_filter` API. But not enough.
Because, Using `trace_filter` for search/filter from first block to 3,000,000 block, needed over 10 minute for finished.
This is not `QUICK`.

I know, this result dependent to server spec and Parity start-up command.
I Used a server has below spec: `AWS EC2 T2.Medium`, Used command: `docker run -d -p 8545:8545 -p 8080:8080 -p 8180:8180 -v $HOME/eth_parity_data:/root/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum --name eth_parity_node parity/parity:stable --fat-db on --tracing on --rpcaddr=0.0.0.0` for start-up Parity on Ubuntu.
Is this server specs and command bad?

Thank you.

Comment: Should I understand `Merkle Tree` on Ethereum? and use ethereumjs/merkle-patricia-tree?

Answer (score 0):

If you want fast lookup of the Ethereum chain. Try [infura.io](http://infura.io/). It's free for now, but eventually it will probably cost money for more than a certain number of lookups, and it's been pretty fast for me for the small bits I've tested it with.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I want fast lookup of the Ethereum chain. But, My client think should not  use other service (like `infura.io`). Because, They wants a knowledge of Ethereum.